# Generate random sequential number by group with multiple times

Tags: r, sample

I'm trying to generate random number by group with multiple times.

For example,

```
> set.seed(1002)
> df<-data.frame(ID=LETTERS[seq(1:5)],num=sample(c(2,3,4), size=5, replace=TRUE))
> df
  ID num
1  A   3
2  B   4
3  C   3
4  D   2
5  E   3
```

In `ID`, I want to generate sequential random number without replacement with (for example) 4 times.

If `ID` is A, it will randomly select numbers among `1:3` 4 times. So, this will be

```
sample(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),replace=FALSE)
```

or

```
ep(sample(c(1:4), replace=FALSE),times=4)
```

If the results is `3 2 1 2 1 3 2 3 3 1 1 2`, then the data will be

```
  ID num
1  A   3
2  A   2
3  A   2
4  A   1
5  A   1
6  A   3
7  A   2
8  A   1
9  A   3
```

I tried several things, like

```
df%>%group_by(ID)%>%mutate(random=sample(rep(1:num,times=4),replace=FALSE))
```

It failed. The `warning` appeared with `In 1:num`

I also tried this.

```
ddply(df,.(ID),function(x) sample(rep(1:num,times=4),replace=FALSE))
```

The error appeared again, with `NA/NaN`.

I would really appreciate if you let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: When you are selecting 4 numbers from `1:3`, this automatically would make it `replace = TRUE`. It would be helpful if you show what your expected output would look like for one of the run.

Comment: default argument in `sample` for `replace` is `FALSE`, so if you don't explicitly mention it, it is considered as `FALSE` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a list-column and then `unnest` it to have separate rows.

```
n <- 4
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(num = list(sample(rep(seq_len(num), n)))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(num)

#  ID      num
#   <fct> <int>
# 1 A         2
# 2 A         2
# 3 A         2
# 4 A         3
# 5 A         3
# 6 A         1
# 7 A         3
# 8 A         1
# 9 A         1
#10 A         3
# … with 50 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on your expected output.

The following samples `num` elements from `1:num` with replacement, and stores samples in a `list` column `sample`.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2018)
df %>% mutate(sample = map(num, ~sample(1:.x, replace = T)))
#  ID num     sample
#1  A   2       1, 1
#2  B   4 3, 4, 1, 2
#3  C   2       1, 1
#4  D   4 3, 3, 4, 4
#5  E   2       2, 2
```

Or if you want to repeat sampling `num` elements (with replacement) 4 times, you can do

```
set.seed(2018)
df %>%
    mutate(sample = map(num, ~as.numeric(replicate(4, sample(1:.x, replace = T)))))
#ID num                                         sample
#1  A   2                         1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1
#2  B   4 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2
#3  C   2                         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2
#4  D   4 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1
#5  E   2                         2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but It's little bit different. Is there another way to represent 'sample' as vector, or column in data.frame? In addition, I will set replace as 'FALSE'.

Comment: @ESKim It would really help if you were to *explicitly* show your expected output for some minimal sample data. That avoids a lot of confusion.

Comment: @ESKim To get your desired output, just `unnest` the results from my second answer part.